# Mockito for Objects in Scala

Tags: scala, object, mockito

I'm using Scala 2.10, specs2 and Mockito. I want to mock scala.io.Source.fromURL(). The issue seems to be fromURL() is a function in [io.Source's object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source%24).

```
val m = mock[io.Source]
m.fromURL returns io.Source.fromString("Some random string.")
```

It's a pretty straightforward mock in an Unit test. Why isn't it working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of mocking it, you could try `spying` it as follows:

```
val m = spy(io.Source)
```

Or you could mock it as follows:

```
val m = mock[io.Source.type]
```

But then how are you using `Source` in the class you are testing?  If you had an example class like so:

```
class MyClass{

  def foo = {
    io.Source.doSomething //I know doSomething is not on Source, call not important
  }
}
```

Then in order to take advantage of mocking/spying, you'd have to structure your class like so:

```
class MyClass{
  val source = io.Source
  def foo = {
    source.doSomething
  }
}
```

And then your test would have to look something like this:

```
val mockSource = mock[io.Source.type]
val toTest = new MyClass{
  override val source = mockSource
}
```

In the Java world, static methods are the bane of mocking.  In the Scala world, calls to objects can also be troublesome to deal with for unit tests.  But if you follow the code above, you should be able to properly mock out an object based dependency in your class.

Comment: Great answer! I'm new to Scala and I find it cumbersome. As a friend said, it looks similar to Dependency Injection pattern.

Comment: Why is mocking mkString of io.BufferedSource not working? It's an instance method: https://gist.github.com/Marius-Stroe/5545901

Comment: I get an error:  Mockito cannot mock/spy following: - final classes
- anonymous classes
- primitive types

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar with object?

Comment: Hey @GismoRanas how you resolve this issue I am facing same error.

Comment: Put your implementation in a trait and have the object `extend` the trait. In this way, the trait can be mocked for testing. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41663795/519951

Comment: I don't think you can mock/spy an object in Scala. You would get something like `Mockito cannot mock/spy because: final class` error

Answer (score 9):

Good news! With the latest 1.16 release of `mockito-scala`, you can now mock scala `object`s.

> To enable withObjectMocked feature, it is mandatory to create the file src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker containing a single line:
>
> ```
> mock-maker-inline
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```scala
> object FooObject {   
>   def simpleMethod: String = "not mocked!"
> }
>
> "mock" should {
>   "stub an object method" in {
>     FooObject.simpleMethod shouldBe "not mocked!"
>
>     withObjectMocked[FooObject.type] {
>       FooObject.simpleMethod returns "mocked!"
>       //or
>       when(FooObject.simpleMethod) thenReturn "mocked!"
>
>       FooObject.simpleMethod shouldBe "mocked!"
>     }
>
>     FooObject.simpleMethod shouldBe "not mocked!"
>   } 
> }
> ```

See: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#mocking-scala-object

Comment: This does not mock objects in the same way that PowerMock mocks statics; the latter accomplishes it via byte code modification of the original object, whereas in my testing it appears that `withObjectMocked` creates a new instance via subclassing. Code under test will still reference the original object unless a reference to the mock is injected.

Answer (score 1):

Years later, above answer doesn't work as others have pointed out.

And you [cannot mock](https://scalamock.org/user-guide/faq/) the `scala.io.Source` object.

> Can I mock final / private methods or classes? This is not supported, as mocks generated with macros are implemented as subclasses of the type to mock. So private and final methods cannot be overridden. You may want to try using an adapter or façade in your code to make it testable. It is better to test against a trait/interface instead of a concrete implementation. There are libraries that support this kind of mocking, such as PowerMock. Be aware that this kind of mocking involves Bytecode manipulation, which has the risk that your test double diverges from the actual implementation.

So what I did is an work around to abstract out `scala.io.Source.fromUrl()` as a function argument and pass in mocked function in tests.

```scala
  // original func
  def aFuncThatUsesSource() = {
    val source = scala.io.Source("127.0.0.1:8080/...")
    val result = source.mkString
    Try(source.close())
    result
  }

  // test friendly func that accepts `scala.io.Source.fromURL` as arg
  def aTestFriendlyFunc(makeApiCall: String => BufferedSource) = {
    val source = makeApiCall("127.0.0.1:8080/...")
    val result = source.mkString
    Try(source.close())
    result
  }

....

  // test spec
  def testyMcTesterson = () => {
    val makeApiCall = mockFunction[String, BufferedSource]
    makeApiCall.expects("something...")
      .returns( new BufferedSource(new ByteArrayInputStream("returns something".getBytes)) )
    aTestFriendlyFunc(makeApiCall) shouldEqual "returns something"
  }
```