# unable to mock XML.load method

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I am trying out ScalaMock in my scala application
What i have is an RSSReader which reads data from XML using `XML.load(<urlString>)`, like in the code below

```
class ScalaRssFinancialDataReader 
  ....
  def fetchRSS(url:String) = XML.load(url) 
  ....
}
```

I am mocking it like this

```
"fetching global economics mocking XML trait" should "return data" in {

  val xmlFragment = <item><title>foo</title><author>a</author></item>
  val xmlMock = mock[scala.xml.XML]
  val tradingEconomicsUrl = "http://www.tradingeconomics.com/russia/rss"

  (xmlMock.load_).expects(tradingEconomicsUrl).returns(xmlFragment)

  val rssReader = new com.worldcorpservices.rss.reader.ScalaRssFinancialDataReader()

  val res = rssReader.fetchRssData("http://www.tradingeconomics.com/russia/rss", "RUSSIA")

  assert(res.size() == 1)

}
```

the problem is that i keep on getting exception that 'XML is not part of p ackage scala.xml

What am i doing wrong here? is it possible to mock XML.load method?

kind regards
 marco

Answer (score 0):

`scala.xml.XML` is an object, Mockito cannot mock objects, you may want to check [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/) (expecially [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects)) for that. What I usually do is create a test file and use that as test case, you don't really need to mock the method.

Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576272/mocking-scala-object) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443801/mockito-for-objects-in-scala).