# How to mock a function within Scala object using Mockito?

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I am really new to Scala. I tried to mock a simple Scala function using Mockito, but I get the following error. I have checked the internet but I was unable to find out the error.

```
object TempScalaService {
  def login(userName: String, password: String): Boolean = {
    if (userName.equals("root") && password.equals("admin123")) {
      return true
    }
    else return false
  }
}
```

And my test class is below

```
class TempScalaServiceTest extends FunSuite with MockitoSugar{

  test ("test login "){
    val service = mock[TempScalaService.type]
    when(service.login("user", "testuser")).thenReturn(true)
    //some implementation
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot mock/spy class     com.pearson.tellurium.analytics.aggregation.TempScalaService$
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
- final classes
- anonymous classes
- primitive types
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class    com.pearson.tellurium.analytics.aggregation.TempScalaService$
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
- final classes
- anonymous classes
- primitive types
   at  org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar$class.mock(MockitoSugar.scala:74)
    at    com.pearson.tellurium.analytics.aggregation.TempScalaServiceTest.mock(Temp    ScalaServiceTest.scala:7)
at     com.pearson.tellurium.analytics.aggregation.TempScalaServiceTest$$anonfun$    1.apply$mcV$sp(TempScalaServiceTest.scala:10)
    at    com.pearson.tellurium.analytics.aggregation.TempScalaServiceTest$$anonfun$    1.apply(TempScalaServiceTest.scala:9)
    at     com.pearson.tellurium.analytics.aggregation.TempScalaServiceTest$$anonfun$    1.apply(TempScalaServiceTest.scala:9)
    at    org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:    22)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.equals()` for Strings in Scala. Try it: `"hi" == new String("hi")` is true. Also, `if (condition) { return true } else return false` can be shortened to just `return condition` or even `condition`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot mock objects, try to move your code to a class:

```
class TempScalaService() {
  def login(userName: String, password: String): Boolean = {
    if (userName.equals("root") && password.equals("admin123")) {
      return true
    }
    else return false
  }
}
```

and create a service:

```
object TempScalaService {
   private val service = TempScalaService()

   def apply() = service
}
```

This would be better with a dependency injection framework, but it will work for now.

Now, for the test, use:

```
val service = mock[TempScalaService]
when(service.login("user", "testuser")).thenReturn(true)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can define the method in a trait which your object extends.  Then simply mock the trait:

```
trait Login {
  def login(userName: String, password: String): Boolean
}

object TempScalaService extends Login {
   def login(userName: String, password: String): Boolean = {
     if (userName.equals("root") && password.equals("admin123")) {
   return true
   }
    else return false
  }
}

//in your test
val service = mock[Login]
```

Comment: This soln works for op question but I have noticed in this approach it doesn't allow you to mock `login` call. ie you can't use `when(mockService.login(any, any)).thenReturn(false)` because when you call `service.login` on mocked service it still internally calls actual login. so you need to provide actual `userName` and `password`.

Answer (score -5):

You can create a Scala Companion Object:

1. Write test cases for you class.
2. Let that object do the external world interaction.